# When data is passed from Activity to Fragment , RecycleView in Fragment shows nothing

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have Firebase RecycleView in Fragment. Its works fine.
The code is as below:

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_banknote_layout,container,false);

        //The next code is working on displaying all users coins per country
        banknotesList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.banknotes_list);
        banknotesList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        banknotesList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        DisplayAllCoins("russia");

        return view;
 }

    private void DisplayAllCoins(final String country_Key) {
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+country_Key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final DatabaseReference coinsTotalRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("admin").child("world_currency").child("year_title_data").child(country_Key);
        Query SortStoriesInDecendingOrder = coinsTotalRef.orderByChild("year_id");

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Banknotes> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Banknotes>()
                        .setQuery(SortStoriesInDecendingOrder, Banknotes.class)
                        .build();


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Banknotes, BanknotesYearViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Banknotes, BanknotesYearViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final BanknotesYearViewHolder viewHolder, int position, @NonNull Banknotes model) {
                        final String Year_Key = getRef(position).getKey();

                        viewHolder.setBanknote_year(model.getBanknote_year());
                        viewHolder.setCurrency(model.getCurrency());
                        viewHolder.setDenomination(model.getDenomination());
                        viewHolder.setComposition(model.getComposition());
                        viewHolder.setColor(model.getColor());
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public BanknotesYearViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_world_currency_year_banknotes_data, viewGroup, false);
                        BanknotesYearViewHolder viewHolder = new BanknotesYearViewHolder(view);
                        return viewHolder;
                    }
                };
        banknotesList.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();


    }
```

But in this case I wrote the country name hardcoded: russia. I want to bring country name from another activity like this:

Code from Activity I send:

```
        FragmentBanknotes fragmentBanknotes=new FragmentBanknotes();
        Bundle banknotes=new Bundle();
        banknotes.putString("data","israel");
        fragmentBanknotes.setArguments(banknotes);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.view_pager,fragmentBanknotes).commit();
```

and now my updated fragment code:

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_banknote_layout,container,false);

        //The next code is working on displaying all users coins per country
        banknotesList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.banknotes_list);
        banknotesList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        banknotesList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


        if(getArguments()!=null) {

            String country_Key = getArguments().getString("data").toLowerCase();
            DisplayAllCoins(country_Key);

        }
        

        return view;
 }

    private void DisplayAllCoins(final String country_Key) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+country_Key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final DatabaseReference coinsTotalRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("admin").child("world_currency").child("year_title_data").child(country_Key);
        Query SortStoriesInDecendingOrder = coinsTotalRef.orderByChild("year_id");

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Banknotes> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Banknotes>()
                        .setQuery(SortStoriesInDecendingOrder, Banknotes.class)
                        .build();


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Banknotes, BanknotesYearViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Banknotes, BanknotesYearViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final BanknotesYearViewHolder viewHolder, int position, @NonNull Banknotes model) {
                        final String Year_Key = getRef(position).getKey();

                        viewHolder.setBanknote_year(model.getBanknote_year());
                        viewHolder.setCurrency(model.getCurrency());
                        viewHolder.setDenomination(model.getDenomination());
                        viewHolder.setComposition(model.getComposition());
                        viewHolder.setColor(model.getColor());
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public BanknotesYearViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_world_currency_year_banknotes_data, viewGroup, false);
                        BanknotesYearViewHolder viewHolder = new BanknotesYearViewHolder(view);
                        return viewHolder;
                    }
                };
        banknotesList.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();


    }
```

I'm checking with Toast and I see , the parameter "israel" is delivered from another activity successfully, but now recycleView shows nothing....
Any ideas, why and what I should change?
(If I will write "israel" hardcoded as before, it will works fine again!)

Comment: Is the key "israel" existing in the Firebase database ? Might sound obvious, but if the Toast is displaying the expected value, it means the bug is after that in the flow.

Comment: Of course. Israel is exist in Firebase. If I will write hardcoded it will works fine!